# Android - Get an Image from the Gallery App?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I need to be able to get an image from the gallery when the user clicks on a button.

Since there are heaps of answers to this, my question is how can I do this, set the selected image to a **RelativeLayout** and this RelativeLayout is in another Class.

My project is set out like this: I have my SettingsActivity which is where the button is, and my MainActivity where the wallpaper is located. I need the image to set to the RelativeLayout when the user navigates back to the MainActivity.

Code I have tried:

SettingsActivity:

```
changeWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view1)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
....
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        editor.putBoolean(SETWALLPAPER, wallpaperSelection);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
isWallpaper = prefs.getBoolean(SETWALLPAPER, false);
...
if(isWallpaper == true)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Setting BG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        wallpaperView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use code to select an image, set a boolean to true in SharedPreferences, and check if the bool is true in my MainActivity, then set the Image. That doesn't work for some reason. @RvdK

Comment: @Nabin Sorry, Just did.

Comment: where do you have your code in main activity? Inside what? OnResume()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity do nothing is because the activity doesn't know what user selected

on SettingActivity `onActivityResult`, you may store `picturePath` in `SharedPreferences`

on MainActivity `onResume`, try to get the path of image and convert it to Bitmap and set it as backgroud drawable

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not setting your picture on selecting the picture **but inside onCreate()**

Put your `if(..){}` inside the **onActivityResult()** method and see.

Let me know if it works.
Use `else` and try to see result. See if the **if** code runs?

Comment: It works for the Toast, just not settings the wallpaper?

Comment: Show every part of code where there is wallpaperView

Comment: Sorry Nabin, @calvinfly had the correct answer, but yours still need appreciation! I voted yours up.